# Should External Routine Be Declared Always in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, external, declaration

In my Fortran code I made the following call to the [`dnrm2`](http://www.netlib.org/blas/dnrm2.f) routine:

```
d = dnrm2(n, ax, 1)
```

Just a simple call that would return me a `double precision` result.

The question is, should I declare the function at the start of my script? I found that if I don't declare it, when I compile the code in 32 bit Windows, then the result is correct.

But if I compile the code in 64 bit Windows, then the result isn't be correct.

Why is this so? Must an external routine always be declared in Fortran?

Comment: What? A downvote? What's the problem with my question?

Comment: +1: This is an interesting question - the downvote makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't correctly describe your subprograms (subroutines and functions) to a calling program, the compiler may not correctly call them.   Fortran compiles each unit separately, so the compiler doesn't "know", by default, about the characteristics of other subprograms.    There are several ways that you can describe/declare a subprogram in Fortran 90/95/2003.

The easiest and best method is to place your subprograms into a module and then "use" that module in the calling program.   This automatically makes the interface known to the compiler and will enable the compiler to check the consistency of actual arguments (in the call) and dummy arguments in the subprogram.  It will also make known the return type of a function.   The various subprograms in a module have their interfaces known to each other.

You can also write an "interface" containing a subprogram declaration that matches the declarations of the actual subprogram.   (This method can be very similar to the style of including header files in C.)  This method is more work and prone to error because you have to manually maintain consistency between the actual subprogram and interface whenever changes are made.   The interface method is useful when you don't have the code to the subprogram or the subprogram is written in a language other than Fortran.

Or you can simply declare a function name to specify the type-return of the function, but this won't give you any checking of the arguments.  In my opinion  this method is weaker since having the compiler check argument consistency eliminates a major class of programming mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

I don't do Fortran, but in C, the size of a pointer and the size of a long int varies between 32 and 64 bit OS'es, but the size of an int does not.  Perhaps the program is using ints to do pointer arithmetic?

Comment: OK, but what does that have to do with my question?